# ansible to perform a task based on hostname value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Hi I am trying below.

```
task:
 - name: Perform on primary server
   blockinfile:
    path: '/home/conf'
    marker: "#-- {mark} Adding Values --"
    block: |
      {{ conf }}
   when: "'host01' in inventory_hostname" 

 - name: Perform on stdby server
   blockinfile:
    path: '/home/conf'
    marker: "#-- {mark} Adding Values --"
    block: |
      {{ conf_stdby }}
   when: "'host02' in inventory_hostname"
```

As every task is performed simultaneously on all hosts, i was expecting it would change `host01` in 1st task and skip `host02` and vice-versa in second task, However it changed in both hosts in both tasks and when i checked the servers both had `conf_stdby`.

Also there are many more tasks in my playbook which are common to both the hosts.

inventory_hostname wouldn't work as in inventory file of playbook there is ip no hostname, so is there a way i can use actual host's hostname in when condition?

Even tried this

```
   vars:
     my_conf:
       host01: "{{ conf }}"
       host02: "{{ conf_stdby }}"
   task:
     - name: Perform on primary server
       blockinfile:
        path: '/home/conf'
        marker: "#-- {mark} Adding Values --"
        block: |
          {{ conf }}
       when: ""{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_hostname}} in myconf"
```

Still both host add the same block

Comment: There are other (and also better) ways to solve your issue, but to stick to your original question "perform task based on hostname", here is a better way: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/2c61c1834e4700ab70ecf609244dbd57

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator for your response, there are many more tasks in my playbook which are common so the link you mentioned doesn’t solve the purpose, I also edited my question to update this detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing all right. The code should work. To test the strings are equal, usually "==" is used instead of the inclusion "in". But, you can reference the configuration data in a dictionary and simplify the code, e.g.

```yaml
vars:
  my_conf:
    host01: "{{ conf }}"
    host02: "{{ conf_stdby }}"
task:
  - blockinfile:
      path: /home/conf
      marker: "#-- {mark} Adding Values --"
      block: |
        {{ my_conf[inventory_hostname] }}
    when: "inventory_hostname in my_conf"
```

---

Q: *"**In the inventory, there is no hostname but ip.**"*

A: Whatever you have got in the inventory put it into the dictionary. There are no restrictions on keys in the YAML dictionaries, e.g. the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
10.1.0.61
10.1.0.62
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_conf:
      10.1.0.61: conf
      10.1.0.62: conf_sdtdby
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_conf[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [10.1.0.61] => 
  msg: conf
ok: [10.1.0.62] => 
  msg: conf_sdtdby
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir for your response, i tried this, it failed with below error which is strange, why did it get ip of the hostname

```{
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'10.x.x.x'\n\n *****,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}```

Comment: It gets what you put into the inventory. [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Comment: My bad @Vladimir, I realised in the inventory there is no hostname but ip, so i don't think i can use this magic variable ```inventory_hostname``` would you know how can we use host's actual hostname in when condition?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Open a new question and make it [mre] if you have more issues.